# Extracting text until reaching the 1st digit - Python

Tags: python, expression

Assume you have the following lines:

```
United States of America 1999 - some text here
United Kingdom 2001.1 - some more text here
Russia - Some extra text here
```

The 3 lines are different (some has an integer, other float, the 3rd has nothing). Country names are also different in length.

How can just extract or print the country names only?

Comment: Is the hyphen `-` character in all the strings? Just split on that, then split on the first occurrence of a digit and take the first result.

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches a sequence of anything that isn't a digit. `\D` matches non-digits.

Comment: Thank you, yes the hyphen is common. Both solutions below worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always - then you can split on `-`

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "United States of America 1999 - some text here"
>>>  re.sub("\d+.?\d*", '', data.split("-")[0]).strip()
'United States of America'
```

we can also use only `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(' ?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]* -.*', '', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.takewhile` to continue grabbing characters until hitting the first non-letter (alpha) or space, then rejoin into a string

```
from itertools import takewhile
def first_text(s):
    return ''.join(takewhile(lambda i: i.isalpha() or i.isspace(), s)).strip()
```

So for example

```
>>> first_text('United States of America 1999 - some text here')
'United States of America'
>>> first_text('United Kingdom 2001.1 - some more text here')
'United Kingdom'
>>> first_text('Russia - Some extra text here')
'Russia'
```